# Traversing hidden li elements

Tags: jquery, count, hidden, html-lists, traversal

I need to add classes to li items in a ul #colorlist at specific places. So every 15th li item becomes one class, every 16th becomes another (the 15th needs a rollover to flip around and the 16th is the first of a row). This is easy enough with this:

```
    $('#colorlist li:nth-child(15n+1)' ).addClass('first-column');
```

However I then have various filters which hide li items and the problem then comes in that the hidden ones are still counted. I think something like this might be the right approach but lots here I'm not sure about. The idea here would be to test if the total number divided by 15 equals a whole number. If it does I'd apply my class.

```
   $("#colorlist li").each(function(){
   if($("#colorlist li:visible").size() % 15 == ???)$(this).addClass('first-column');
   });
```

Not sure how you test for a whole number, or how you would use it for every 15th item. As you can see I'm sort of lost! Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How do you hide your `li` elements? If you use `display:none` they won't be counted.

Comment: I am using jquery show and hide commands. According to firebug "hide" gives them a display:none but the nth-child still counts them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want:

```
$("#colorlist li:visible")
  .filter(function(i){ return i % 15 === 0;})
  .addClass('first-column');
```

This will compute the position only taking the visible elements into account.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/e8s6H/12/)

Comment: +1, could cut it down even a few more characters with `return !(i % 15)`

Comment: Many thanks this worked great. Just to note for any other rank beginners like me reading this - I changed it to (i+1) % 15 === 0, which gets rid of the first li getting the class and makes it visually every 15th li that gets it.

Comment: @hmon: I was not sure about that one, because `:nth-child(15n+1)` in your first code example also selects the first element. But anyway :) You could also do `i % 15 === 14`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your passing every li element to jQuery.each. Try:

```
$("#colorlist li:visible").each(function(i, elem){
   var $el = $(this);
   //If is 0 add class
   if( i % 15 === 0 ){
       $el.addClass('first-column');
   }
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/473ky/